# How to read row one at a time in Datagrid Wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, rows

How can i read each row in Datagrid one at a time.

For example my datagrid has 5 data on it. And each data corresponds to a method /  function in my C# solution.

I want to read it as data 1 then perform the corresponding function under that data.
then read data 2 then perform the corresponding function under that data 2. and so on..

Can anyone give me some idea how?

Comment: Have you tried anything? foreach / for ?

Comment: are you using data binding or code behind approach. would be nice if you add some concerned code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are not following MVVM, Get the Items From Your DataGrid like this,

```
    var tmplist = (ObservableCollection<YourDataGridObject>)DataGrid.ItemsSource;
    foreach (YourDataGridObjectitm in tmplist)
    {
    ///Access elements
    }
```